# How to create a PHP script interacting with Magento Model

Tags: php, magento

I want to create a custom PHP script which runs outside of Magento in a different folder (same domain) that interacts with the Magento Model classes.

Which includes and which calls should I perform to get access to it. I remember that this would be possible but I don't remember how.

Answer (score 1):

Write this in your php file

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');

//add your own code below:
//load a product
$_product= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1);

//load a category
$_product= Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize magento by including the Mage.php file and than calling Mage::app(). Than you can call your model the magento way ( Mage::getModel() )

```
require '/path/to/app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
$myModel = Mage::getModel('myModel/my');
```

Hope that helps.